# Can an AI model licensed under the BigScience RAIL License v1.0 be used in a program that is useful for any domain?

Tags: licensing, open-source-software, artificial-intelligence

Example: the AI model [BLOOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOOM_(language_model)) is licensed under the [BigScience RAIL License v1.0](https://huggingface.co/spaces/bigscience/license). The BigScience RAIL License v1.0 forbids that some types of usages:

> You agree not to use the Model or Derivatives of the Model:
>
> [...]
>
> - To provide medical advice and medical results interpretation;
> - To generate or disseminate information for the purpose to be used for administration of justice, law enforcement, immigration or asylum processes, such as predicting an individual will commit fraud/crime commitment (e.g. by text profiling, drawing causal relationships between assertions made in documents, indiscriminate and arbitrarily-targeted use).

Am I allowed to use BLOOM in a program that is useful for any domain (e.g., a program to summarize or paraphrase some text, or perform question-answer on a text, or generate questions and their answers based on the text)?

Since people could use the program for any domain, they could technically, for example, use the program to summarize a medical report or generate questions and their answers based on some asylum process to distribute to potential applicants.

Comment: Have you read paragraph 4 of the license? That seems to me to address your question as written; if not, could you edit to clarify your question?

Comment: @DanGetz got it, looks like the answer there indeed "Use-based restrictions as referenced in paragraph 5 MUST be included as an enforceable provision by You in any type of legal agreement (e.g. a license) governing the use and/or distribution of the Model or Derivatives of the Model, and You shall give notice to subsequent users You Distribute to, that the Model or Derivatives of the Model are subject to paragraph 5. This provision does not apply to the use of Complementary Material."

Comment: @DanGetz tldr my program should use some license/agreement/ToS banning these use cases listed under "You agree not to use the Model or Derivatives of the Model", from my understanding.